# How to javascript split on first "("

Tags: javascript, regex, split

So i want to split my var at the first ( in the var. My code looks like this for the moment but it doesn't work.

```
var word = "pc and (laptop or test)";
var split = word.split(/((.+)/);
```

Value of 'split' = `[ '', 'pc and (communication or (test and test2))', '' ]`

wanted result: `['pc and ', ' communication or (test and test2))']`

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: If no other `(` then `word.split("(")` works

Comment: I only want the first `(` to be splitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to take the index of the character and slice the string.

```js
var word = "pc and (laptop or test) (or something other)",
    index = word.indexOf('('),
    split = index == -1 ? [word] : [word.slice(0, index), word.slice(index + 1)]

console.log(split);
```

Comment: If only one, why not `word.split("(")`

Comment: I only want the first '(' to be splitted.